# Monaco Editor In Electron with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, monaco-editor

### Preface

I am not a web-dev. I repeat, *I am not a web developer.* I have just begun embarking into the world of npm, JS, TS, React, etc coming from a very mobile/desktop-oriented background. Please, dumb-down any answers Barney-style in recognition of this.

### Synopsis

I'm trying to get Microsoft's [Monaco Editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) working in [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) with [React](https://reactjs.org/), using [Electron Forge](https://electronforge.io/). However, I don't understand the error I'm receiving. I've read some things on issues with the non-standard ways Microsoft does some AMD load thing that people have had issues with for years. I can't *determine a solution* based on my findings. The [closest SO post I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698674/imports-not-finding-modules-and-namespaces-with-react-monaco-editor-in-typescrip) has no answer. I tried the same process for the [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/) and it worked perfectly; however, I would *strongly* prefer to use the Monaco editor in my application if possible.

---

### Electron + React + Monaco

```
$ electron-forge init electron-monaco-test --template=react
$ cd electron-monaco-test
$ yarn add react-monaco-editor
```

I then edit **src/app.jsx** to:

```
import React from 'react';
import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <MonacoEditor language='javascript' />;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
$ npm start
```

I receive the following error referencing `module.js:545`:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'monaco-editor'
>       at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/Zac/Dev/electron-monaco-test/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:473:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (/Users/Zac/Dev/electron-monaco-test/node_modules/react-monaco-editor/lib/editor.js:11:21)
>       at Object. (/Users/Zac/Dev/electron-monaco-test/node_modules/react-monaco-editor/lib/editor.js:188:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Zac/Dev/electron-monaco-test/node_modules/electron-compile/lib/require-hook.js:77:14)
>       at Module.load (module.js:561:32)

I also tried adding `monaco-editor` as a direct project dependency but that didn't work, either.

---

### Electron + React + Ace Editor

When I apply the exact same process to Ace Editor it just works.

```
$ electron-forge init electron-ace-test --template=react
$ cd electron-ace-test
$ yarn add react-ace
```

**src/app.jsx**:

```
import React from 'react';
import AceEditor from 'react-ace'

import 'brace/theme/github'
import 'brace/mode/javascript'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AceEditor
        mode='javascript'
        theme='github' />
    );
  }
}
```

Then:

```
$ npm start
```

---

Any suggestions on how to fix the setup for Monaco?

Comment: At first glance it seems like `react-monaco-editor` expects to be used with webpack.

Comment: do you still need help?